# Using Apache2 behind HAProxy is not working properly

Tags: wordpress, apache, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm using apache 2.2 on ubuntu 12.04 behind haproxy 1.5. My haproxy is listening on port 80 and apache is listening on port 8000. What I'm trying to do is that I want to forward any request that comes on haproxy with path "/test" to a my apache.

I have an wordpress application hosted in "/var/www/test".

The problem I'm facing is that if I try to access test app using **http://www.example.com/test**, apache redirected it to **http://www.example.com:8000/test/** .  Any idea why this is happening?. What am I missing?

and here is the the configurations:

ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8000
Listen 8000

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 </VirtualHost>
```

haproxy.cfg:

```
frontend http-in
      bind *:80
      acl is_test path_beg /test
      use_backend test_backend if is_test

backend test_backend
      balance roundrobin
      option forwardfor
      server Local localhost:8000 check
```

Also I figured out that $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] is empty when i log it in index.php. Any idea why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Wordpress. Check your "Site Address (URL)" setting. Wordpress is redirecting the browser to where it sees itself as being hosted. Changing the "Site Address (URL)" setting to http://www.example.com/test should stop this.